# Ms Teams Bot unable to load using task module on iframe

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

I'm currently creating ms teams bot, i want to use task module to load my app login page, so i just tried to mimic the [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-task-module/nodejs) which load youtube page for now.
i tried to use the sample. It is using adaptive card and here is the action code

```
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "title": "YouTube",
      "data": {
        "taskModuleId": "YouTube",
        "type": "task/fetch"
      }
    }
```

when i click it, it's correctly triggering:

```
  async handleTeamsTaskModuleFetch(context: TurnContext, taskModuleRequest: TaskModuleRequest): Promise<TaskModuleResponse> {

    const cardTaskFetchValue = taskModuleRequest.data.taskModuleId;
    var taskInfo = {url: '', fallbackUrl: ''}; // TaskModuleTaskInfo

    if (cardTaskFetchValue === TaskModuleIds.CustomForm) {
        // Display the CustomForm.html page, and post the form data back via
        // handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit.
        taskInfo.url = taskInfo.fallbackUrl = 'https://' + this.baseUrl + '/' + TaskModuleIds.CustomForm + '.html';
        this.setTaskInfo(taskInfo, TaskModuleUIConstants.CustomForm);
    } else if (cardTaskFetchValue === TaskModuleIds.YouTube) {
        // Display the CustomForm.html page, and post the form data back via
        // handleTeamsTaskModuleSubmit.
        taskInfo.url = taskInfo.fallbackUrl = 'https://' + this.baseUrl + '/' + TaskModuleIds.YouTube+ '.html';
        this.setTaskInfo(taskInfo, TaskModuleUIConstants.YouTube);
    }

    return Promise.resolve(TaskModuleResponseFactory.toTaskModuleResponse(taskInfo));
  }
```

i tried to debug the return value `Promise.resolve()`

```
{
    "type": "continue",
    "value": {
        "fallbackUrl": "https://******.asse.devtunnels.ms/YouTube.html",
        "height": 700,
        "title": "YouTube",
        "url": "https://******.asse.devtunnels.ms/YouTube.html",
        "width": 1000
    }
}
```

when i copy the link and manually load that page from chrome its work fine,

[image]

but from ms teams its just blank and when i check the chrome console i saw :
[image]
**Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'prefetch-src'.**

any idea what i should check related to this issue? or maybe anything else that might cause it to be blank?

EDIT i think i found a clue that lead to another question, i believe that i added the validDomains, since i had it on my manifest and the teams toolkit seems like adding it automatically, but when i check it's not there, and when i manually adding it, it popped an error :

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.15/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "permissions": [
        "identity",
        "messageTeamMembers"
    ],
    "validDomains": [
        "https://${{BOT_DOMAIN}}"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "id": "${{AAD_APP_CLIENT_ID}}",
        "resource": "api://botid-${{BOT_ID}}"
    }
}
```

but when i check it's not there, and when i manually adding it, it popped an error :
[image]

i tried add *.asse.devtunnels.ms, i also added the youtube.com, i tried add multiple combination but the error persist. can someone tell me the correct way of adding this?

EDIT 2 : i finally found the issue, since i use the typescript sample initially, but then tried to mimic the js sample, i did some clean up /pages dir html files and js (removed unused one) fixed the issue. however the issue now with

[image]

Comment: We are also encountering the same error, but the task module for YouTube is displaying correctly. Have you received any other error messages so that we can investigate further?
[![enter image description here][1]][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1We3c.png

Comment: also, could you please try with the below manifest as well-[bot-task-module.zip](https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/files/12511832/bot-task-module.zip)

Comment: hi @Sayali-MSFT, thanks for commenting, i found the issue i think, some error happened around the sample, i didnt copy paste the sample but i manually typed it since i used the typescript one. i think the js file on the sample did not load properly.  now all works fine, its just that this page loaded first before going to the youtube ( will update my question)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share my approach of fixing the issue, initially i thought its an issue with CSP. The csp error msg still there but the page is loaded fine

1. narrow down the issue by loading all the pages on /pages that are available, load it on jsfiddle
2. use the ms teams on web to be able to check the devtools
3. make sure you add the validDomains on your manifest in your code and in azure active directory (this is still investigated)